# PHrets - Using PHP to create mysql tables from rets - Script

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, rets, phrets

I found this piece of code online which will connect to the rets feed and create mysql tables.

```
<?php 

/* Raw example on how to use phrets to generate the necessary sql code 
for mysql tables generation from rets. 
Works for me*/ 

require ('phrets0.6.1.php'); 


$rets = new phRETS; 

$Host = 'http://demo.crt.realtors.org:6103/rets/login'; 
$Account = 'Joe'; 
$Password = 'Schmoe'; 
$User_Agent = 'RETS_class/1.0'; 
$Rets_Version = 'RETS/1.5' ; 



$rets->AddHeader("Accept", "*/*"); 
$rets->AddHeader("RETS-Version", "$Rets_Version"); 
$rets->AddHeader("User-Agent", "$User_Agent"); 
$rets->SetParam("cookie_file", "phrets_cookies.txt"); 
//$rets->SetParam("debug_mode", TRUE); // ends up in rets_debug.txt 


$rets->Connect($Host,$Account,$Password); 
        $ResourcesInfo1 = $rets->GetMetadataInfo(); 
        $MetadataInfo1 = $rets->GetMetadataTypes(); 
/*testing4GetTables*/ 
function GetTables($ResourcesInfo, $MetadataInfo) { 
/*        Put toghether all the rets info needed for database tables creation 
in an array. */ 
        foreach ($MetadataInfo as $key => $value){ 
                $Resource = $value['Resource']; 
                foreach ($value['Data'] as $key){ 
                        $tables[$key['Description']] = array( 
                                                                                'ResourceID' => $Resource, 
                                                                                'Description' => $key['Description'], 
                                                                                'ClassName' => $key['ClassName'] , 
                                                                                 'KeyField' => $ResourcesInfo[$Resource]['KeyField'], 
                                                                                'ClassCount' => $ResourcesInfo[$Resource]['ClassCount'] 
                                                                                ); 
                } 

        } 
        return $tables; 
} 

function CreateMysqlTables ($ResourcesInfo, $MetadataInfo, $class){ 
/*function providing the mysql code needed to create mysqltables. 
to be run as the script on the commande line for nicer output*/ 
        $table = GetTables($ResourcesInfo, $MetadataInfo); 

        foreach ($table as $key => $value){ 

                $TablesAndFields[$value['Description']] = $class- 
>GetMetadata($value['ResourceID'],$value['ClassName']); 
        } 

        foreach ($TablesAndFields as $key => $value){ 
                $find = array ('/ /', '/-/'); 
                $TableName = preg_replace($find, "_", $key); 
                echo "\n\r CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TableName  (\n\r"; 
                 foreach ( $value as $key2 => $value2){ 
                                 echo "`$value2[SystemName]` "; 
                                 ConvertTypeToMysql($value2[DataType], $value2[MaximumLength]); 
                 } 
                 echo "`MyNewTablesTimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL default 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n\r"; 
        echo " PRIMARY KEY (".$table[$key]['KeyField']."));\n\r"; 
        } 
} 

function ConvertTypeToMysql($datatype, $datalenght){ 
/*        This function  to convert mls datatype and datalenght to mysql. 
        Change to fit your needs works for me: db2 to mysql (flexmls)*/ 
        switch ($datatype){ 
        case "Character": 
                if ($datalenght >= 255){ 
                        echo "text  collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL, \n\r"; 

                } 
                elseif (!$datalenght){ 
                        echo "$datatype(25) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL, \n\r"; 

                } 
                else { 
                        echo "$datatype($datalenght) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL, 
\n\r"; 

                } 

                break; 

        case "Decimal": 

                echo "$datatype($datalenght,0) default NULL, \n\r"; 
                break; 

        case "Int": 

                echo "$datatype($datalenght) default NULL, \n\r"; 
                break; 

        case "Long": 
/*                note:if I put this case after case ("Date" or "Boolean"): it won't 
work, Why? is Long a Boolean?'*/ 
                echo "LONGTEXT collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL, \n\r"; 
                break; 

        case ("Date" or "Boolean"): 

                echo "$datatype default NULL, \n\r"; 
                break; 


        } 

} 
CreateMysqlTables ($ResourcesInfo1, $MetadataInfo1, $rets); 

$rets->Disconnect(); 

?>
```

Sorry for the long piece of code.

I have established a connection to my Wordpress site through FTP using my IDE and have the PHrets files loaded on there.

My final goal is to populate mysql database with all of the listings in the rets feed and then have my website work off of that while the database is updated every so often checking for updated or new listings.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you having any specific issues with this code, or are you wondering how to get this working with wordpress?

Comment: @slim slim, how to get it working with wordpress. I would really appreciate it man

Comment: Might take me a while to get back to you with this, but I'll try.

Comment: What MLS are you connecting to? Are you (or your client) a member of an MLS?

Comment: @Adrian World monroe county, florida mls. The florida keys. Yes they are a member of the mls. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

Okay, before I offer a few pointers here's the easy path when you want to operate under IDX rules (i.e. this would not apply for VOW). Forget about RETS and getting your own data feed. Maybe using an IDX provider is a better way to get your data. Take a look at these two: IDX Broker http://www.idxbroker.com/mls/florida-keys-mls-flkmls or http://www.diversesolutions.com/idx-coverage/floridakeysmls-410. I'm not sure if that is your MLS and there are quite a few more IDX providers. You should be able to get a full list talking to your MLS because IDX providers have to register with each and every MLS.

If you want to or need your own RETS feed and DB here are some pointers

- I used PHRETS once a few years ago--since then I've build my own client. I'm not uptodate on PHRETS but it looks like you are using a very old client `phrets0.6.1.php`. You should take a look at https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS and version 2.
- Look at its Wiki pages for more information https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki
- If you want to know more about RETS you can find more at RESO (Real Estate Standards Organisation) and their specifications here  http://www.reso.org/specifications. Check with your MLS what RETS version they are using.
- Although RETS as a standard should help you *get the data* (because it is a transfer protocol) it does not define how to format the actual data with the feed. RESO is working for more than a decade on the RESO dictionary which should normalize the data across all the MLS but that is still in the works and we will never know how long it will take for all the 900+ MLS to adopt this standard.